# combine information from multi line log to single line

Tags: logging, awk, sed, grep, filtering

I have a java application log file containing some parameters i want to pick on different lines, i want it all on a single line.

Log Example:

```
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter start
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client IP Address : 172.25.4.32
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client User-Agent : Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.2; Nexus 5X Build/N2G47O)
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter end
2017-05-31 16:30:38.891 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.controller.MyDataController - Start getMyPageResponse method, input = {"token":"AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse"}
2017-05-31 16:30:38.891 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - Start getMyPageInfo method, requestDto = TokenRequestDto [token=AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse]
2017-05-31 16:30:38.891 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - Start authentication token=AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse
2017-05-31 16:30:38.895 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - End authentication, UserInfo=UserInfoDto[userID=123456789]
2017-05-31 16:30:38.895 [http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - userID = 123456789, token = AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse
2017-05-31 16:30:39.422 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - End getMyPageInfo method
2017-05-31 16:30:39.423 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - Start getMyPageResponse method
2017-05-31 16:30:39.423 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - End getMyPageResponse method
2017-05-31 16:30:39.423 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.controller.MyDataController - End getMyPageResponse method, Total Computation/Execution Time : 0.532s

2017-05-31 16:42:36.500 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter start
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client IP Address : 172.25.4.32
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client User-Agent : MyiOSApp/v2.2.2 (build:888; iOS 10.3.2) Alamofire/4.4.0
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter end
2017-05-31 16:42:36.506 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.controller.MyDataController - Start getMyPageResponse method, input = {"token":"KingLionMonkeyNestOwlParrotQueenRabbitSnakeTiger"}
2017-05-31 16:42:36.507 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - Start authentication token=KingLionMonkeyNestOwlParrotQueenRabbitSnakeTiger
2017-05-31 16:42:36.507 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - Start getMyPageInfo method
2017-05-31 16:42:36.515 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - End authentication, UserInfo=UserInfoDto[userID=987654321]
2017-05-31 16:42:36.515 [http-listener-1(3)] DEBUG com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - userID = 987654321, token = KingLionMonkeyNestOwlParrotQueenRabbitSnakeTiger
2017-05-31 16:42:36.743 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - End getMyPageInfo method
2017-05-31 16:42:36.743 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - Start getMyPageResponse method
2017-05-31 16:42:36.743 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - End getMyPageResponse method
2017-05-31 16:42:36.743 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.controller.MyDataController - End getMyPageResponse method, Total Computation/Execution Time : 0.237s
```

Filter Example 1:

```
cat /usr/local/sun/glassfish/domains/universal-api/logs/my-new-api/system.log | grep -e "Filter" -e "userID"

2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter start                                                                                                     
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client IP Address : 172.25.4.32                                                                                                         
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client User-Agent : MyiOSApp/v2.2.2 (build:888; iOS 10.3.2) Alamofire/4.4.0                                                       
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter end                                                                                                       
2017-05-31 16:30:38.895 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - End authentication, UserInfo=UserInfoDto[userID=123456789]                                                                                   
2017-05-31 16:30:38.895 [http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - userID = 123456789, token = AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse                                                                               
2017-05-31 16:42:36.500 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter start                                                                                                     
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client IP Address : 172.25.4.32                                                                                                         
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client User-Agent : Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.2; Nexus 5X Build/N2G47O)                                                       
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - ContainerRequestContextFilter end                                                                                                       
2017-05-31 16:42:36.515 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - End authentication, UserInfo=UserInfoDto[userID=987654321]                                                                                   
2017-05-31 16:42:36.515 [http-listener-1(3)] DEBUG com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - userID = 987654321, token = KingLionMonkeyNestOwlParrotQueenRabbitSnakeTiger
```

Filter Example 2:

```
cat /usr/local/sun/glassfish/domains/universal-api/logs/my-new-api/system.log | grep -e "IP Address" -e "User-Agent" -e "userID"

2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client IP Address : 172.25.4.32                                                                                                         
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client User-Agent : MyiOSApp/v2.2.2 (build:888; iOS 10.3.2) Alamofire/4.4.0                                                       
2017-05-31 16:30:38.895 [http-listener-1(2)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - End authentication, UserInfo=UserInfoDto[userID=123456789]                                                                                   
2017-05-31 16:30:38.895 [http-listener-1(2)] DEBUG com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - userID = 123456789, token = AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse                                                                               
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client IP Address : 172.25.4.32                                                                                                         
2017-05-31 16:42:36.501 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.api.provider.ClientRequestDataFilter - Client User-Agent : Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.2; Nexus 5X Build/N2G47O)                                                       
2017-05-31 16:42:36.515 [http-listener-1(3)] INFO  com.domain.biz.logic.impl.UserAuthBizLogic - End authentication, UserInfo=UserInfoDto[userID=987654321]                                                                                   
2017-05-31 16:42:36.515 [http-listener-1(3)] DEBUG com.domain.biz.service.impl.MyTestService - userID = 987654321, token = KingLionMonkeyNestOwlParrotQueenRabbitSnakeTiger
```

I want to filter out 4 things from these:

time, IP Address, user-agent, userID, token

Sample Expected Output:

```
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889, 172.25.4.32, MyiOSApp/v2.2.2 (build:888; iOS 10.3.2) Alamofire/4.4.0, 123456789
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889, 172.25.4.32, Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.2; Nexus 5X Build/N2G47O), 987654321
```

and print them all in one line.

they will appear in the same sequence always.

in order to assist with text selection i added `ContainerRequestContextFilter start` and `ContainerRequestContextFilter end`

I believe a combination of **`grep`**,**`awk`**, **`sed`** & **`tr`** can help me do the job, is there any other efficient way?

***Update***: The problem is there are many such entries one after another for multiple users. I wonder if writing a shell script, python code or similar techniques would be more efficient.

i could get only 1 line using awk on the multiline logs,
i need 1 line per user.

Comment: Did you make an attempt yourself to solve this?

Comment: is this you want ? `awk -v OFS=,  '/ContainerRequestContextFilter start/{time=$1 " " $2;next} /Client IP Address/{ipAddress=$NF;next} /Client User-Agent/{n=split($0,a,"Client User-Agent :");userAgent=a[n];next} /userID =/{m=split($0,b,"userID =");userIDAndToken=b[m];next}END{print time,ipAddress,userAgent,userIDAndToken}'` ?

Comment: why it should start from `12:05:11.813` ?

Comment: remove your `start` and `end` as they make your input confusing and they are not presented in your actual input

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i wanted to take the first access/hit time, but since the difference is hardly much, any time is okay. i need to check when there are too many concurrent users though if the delay is too high.

Comment: @PS. Thanks for the beautiful awk snippet. Can you check the updated part please. i need multiple users information, not just one.

Comment: @computingfreak may be this helps `sed '/Client User-Agent/ s/$/@/'|awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' |awk -v OFS=,  '{match($0,/Client IP Address : ([^ ]+).*Client User-Agent :([^@]+).*userID = ([^ ]+).*token = ([^ ]+)/,a);gsub(/,/,"",a[3]);print $1,$2,a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk '!f && /ContainerRequestContextFilter/{ f=1; t=$1 FS $2; next }
     /Client IP Address/{ ip=$NF; next }
     /Client User-Agent/{ uagent=$10; for(i=11;i<=NF;i++) uagent=uagent FS $i; next }
     /userID =.* token =/{ match($0,/userID = ([0-9]+), token = (.+)/,a); f=0; 
      printf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n",t,ip,uagent,a[1],a[2]); next}
' system.log
```

The output:

```
2017-05-31 16:30:38.889, 172.25.4.32, Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.2; Nexus 5X Build/N2G47O), 123456789, AppleBallCatDogElephantFoxGoatHorse
2017-05-31 16:42:36.500, 172.25.4.32, MyiOSApp/v2.2.2 (build:888; iOS 10.3.2) Alamofire/4.4.0, 987654321, KingLionMonkeyNestOwlParrotQueenRabbitSnakeTiger
```

---

- `!f && /ContainerRequestContextFilter/` - processing the starting `ContainerRequestContextFilter` line
- `/Client IP Address/{ ip=$NF; next }` - processing line containing `Client IP Address` value
- `/Client User-Agent/` - processing line matching `Client User-Agent`
- `/userID =.* token =/` - processing line matching `userID =` and `token =`

Comment: i removed the "!f &&" and it works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already direct the output of `cat /usr/local/sun/glassfish/domains/universal-api/logs/my-new-api/system.log | grep -e "Filter" -e "userID"` to the file named `log`.

And then you can try following `awk` command to achieve your goal,

```
awk '
  /ContainerRequestContextFilter start/ {printf "%s %s,",$1,$2}
  /Client User-Agent/ {for(i=10;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ",$i}
  /userID/ {printf ", %s",$9}
  /token/ {printf " %s\n",$12}
' log
```

The output shall be as your request.